# Sort by selectRaw relationship in Laravel (calculated count, sum ...)

Tags: php, sorting, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a `Question` model which have morphMany `Answer`. `Answer` have also morphMany `Answer` and `Rating`

I added relationship to calculate and load `Answer` count and `Answer` rating sum :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Facades\AuthManager;

class Answer extends Model {
protected $with = [
        'user',
        'cards',
        'answers.user',
        'answersCountRelation',
        'ratingSumRelation'
];
protected $fillable = [
        'text',
        'user_id'
];

public function answerable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function answers() {
    return $this->morphMany(Answer::class, 'answerable');
}

public function reports() {
    return $this->morphMany(Report::class, 'reportable');
}

public function cards() {
    return $this->hasMany(Card::class);
}

public function ratings() {
    return $this->hasMany(Rating::class);
}

public function hasReported(User $user) {
    return ($user != null && $this->reports()->where([
            'user_id' => $user->id
    ])->first() != null);
}

public function hasRated(User $user) {
    return ($user != null && $this->ratings()->where([
            'user_id' => $user->id
    ])->first() != null);
}

public function answersCountRelation() {
    return $this->answers()->selectRaw('answerable_id, count(*) as count')->groupBy('answerable_id');
}

public function getAnswersCountAttribute() {
    return ($this->answersCountRelation->first() ? $this->answersCountRelation->first()->count : 0);
}

public function ratingSumRelation() {
    return $this->ratings()->selectRaw('answer_id, SUM(power) as sum')->groupBy('answer_id');
}

public function getRatingSumAttribute() {
    return ($this->ratingSumRelation->first() ? $this->ratingSumRelation->first()->sum : 0);
}
}
```

Now I wonder how can I load `Question` with `Answer` already sorted by answer count, rating, created_at etc

Is it possible to do it using the already eager loaded `answersCountRelation` or `ratingSumRelation` ?

Or do I have to do another request in `Question->with(['answers' => function ($q) ...`

Thx !